# Transcribing baptism entry from Oberellenbach in 1697

Tags: church-records, kurrent, german, 1690s

[image]

So far, I have this:

```
den 17 Maj ist Elisabeth Schweitzern in [?] von 
[Zielkes?] kind mit Hans jacob [?] getaufft 
u. ihm d. nahme Martha Elisabeth von johanneß [?] 
Tochter von Cunnefeld gegeben worden.
```

Can you help me to complete this transcription?